# Помогите отредактировать неправильно работающий код

Tags: html, css

Передо мной стоит задача написать код согласно условиям, что приведены на изображении.

Код уже написан, но возникла одна проблема - это постоянное всплывание окна "Мы вам перезвоним !", которое должно всплывать лишь при цифровых значениях больше десяти, но оно всплывает и при меньших значениях. Соответственно для значений меньше 10 окно "Перестаньте баловаться !" не всплывает... Не могу понять, что не так в коде...

[image: Вот условия.]

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (age < 10 || age > 100)
    alert("Перестаньте баловаться !");
  else alert("Мы вам перезвоним !");
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
}
```

```html
<h1> Хотите найти работу ? Тогда вы пришли прямо по адресу ! </h1>
<hr>
<p style="color:#000080"><em><big>Ответьте всего на один вопрос, и узнайте, подходите ли вы нам, или нет.</big></em> </p>
<input type="text" size="40">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check Age</button>
<hr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<h1> Хотите найти работу ? Тогда вы пришли прямо по адресу ! </h1>
<hr>

<p style="color:#000080"><em><big>Ответьте всего на один вопрос, и узнайте, подходите ли вы нам, или нет.</big></em> </p>
<input type="text" size="40" id="age">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Check Age</button>
<hr>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var age = +document.getElementById("age").value;
    if (age >= 10 && age <= 100)
      alert("Мы вам перезвоним !");
    else 
      alert("Перестаньте баловаться !");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Gloom Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @Gloom укажите ответ как "верный"